# Check a string that holds a variable

Tags: php

In PHP I want to check a string that holds a variable by escaping the variable in my test. I think that there is something to replace `random_id` by a token or maybe a regex but im not able to find the good way.

An idea ?

Example :

```
  function test($string) {
    if ($string == 'start/random_id/end') {
      return 'random_id/end';
    }
  }
```

(random_id that can be any string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to check for the pattern, maybe it is an option for you to use a regex using [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

[^start/(.+)/end$](https://regex101.com/r/eX55h3/1/)

You can capture your `random_id` in a group and reference it using  `$matches[1]`.

For example:

```
function test($string) {
    if (preg_match("/^start\/(.+)\/end$/", $string, $matches)) {
        return "$matches[1]/end";
    }
    return $string;

}

echo test("start/1b2c3!@#$/end") . PHP_EOL;
echo test("/end") . PHP_EOL;
echo test("start/1b2c3!@#$/en") . PHP_EOL;
echo test("start//end") . PHP_EOL;
```

That would give you:

```
1b2c3!@#$/end
/end
start/1b2c3!@#$/en
start//end
```

Right now if it does not match, the input `$string` is returned but you could change that to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: updated per comment..

This should work:

```
function test($string) {
    $prefix = "start/";
    $suffix = "/end";
    if (substr($string, 0, strlen($prefix)) === $prefix &&
        substr($string, -strlen($suffix)) === $suffix) {  

        return substr($string, strlen($prefix));
    } else {
        return $string; // I guess? otherwise you return nothing..
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do it like this because my test function doesn't know the $randomId var ... The $string is already processed at this point.